# Extract XML data to excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba

Hi so i found this code online that can help me extract data from an xml document.
This code looks like this:

```
Function fnReadXMLByTags()
Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Clear
Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFileName = "D:\Sample.xml"
oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)
Set TitleNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/title/text()")
Set PriceNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/price/text()")
mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1,B1,C1").Interior.ColorIndex = 40
mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1,B1,C1").Borders.Value = 1
mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & 1).Value = "Book ID"
mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & 1).Value = "Book Titles"
mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & 1).Value = "Price"
mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value = "Total books: " & TitleNodes.Length

    For i = 0 To (TitleNodes.Length - 1)
        Title = TitleNodes(i).NodeValue
        Price = PriceNodes(i).NodeValue
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i + 2).Borders.Value = 1
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i + 2).Borders.Value = 1
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i + 2).Value = Title
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i + 2).Value = Price
Next
'Reading the Attributes
Set Nodes_Attribute = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book")
For i = 0 To (Nodes_Attribute.Length - 1)
    Attributes = Nodes_Attribute(i).getAttribute("id")
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i + 2).Borders.Value = 1
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i + 2).Value = Attributes
Next
End Function
```

Which works great for an XML that looks like this

```
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
                                      with XML.</description>
   </book>
```

However my XML data looks more like this

```
<catalog>
   <cbc:book="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <cac:title>XML Developer's Guide</cac:title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <cac:price>44.95</cac:price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </cbc:book>
```

i tried changing this part in the code:

```
Set TitleNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/cac:title/text()")
Set PriceNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book/cac:price/text()")
```

The cac and cbc seems to do something that stops the code from working.
Do you know what i can do to get around this? Thanks.

Comment: cac and cbc are namespaces defined at start of xml doc. A tag 'book' is in the default namespace of the xml document, whereas 'cbc:book' is in the cbc namespace - so 'book' and 'cbc:book' are different tags, which is why SelectNode doesn't match 'cbc:book'. Don't know how you solve that problem except by making the code more attentive to namespaces. Either that or hacky horrors like removing the namespaces are possible there are plenty of q/a on here if you search for _remove xml namespace_. You might be able configure Microsoft.XMLDOM to ignore namespaces but not sure